# Search for a number from the suggested (Python, Discord, bot)

Tags: python, discord, bots

I want the bot to stop when it finds the number 2, I also don’t understand why it responds with numbers in brackets

```
if message.content.startswith('FindNumber2') or ("1") or ("3") or ("4"):
    time.sleep(2)
    await message.channel.send(random.choices(list4, weights=(100, 30, 59, 40)))

list4 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtPVP.png)

Comment: Could you describe the question with more information? Like what you actually send and what do you want as output?

Comment: I want the bot to iterate over the numbers until it finds the right one (2)
It seems that everything is clear there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers are in brackets because you use `random.choices` which, when the fourth parameter k is not specified, will default to returning a list of one number. It is these lists of one number that you are seeing. The bot is not stopping because `message.content.startswith(thing) or (other_thing)` is not the same as `message.content.startswith(thing) or message.content.startswith(other_thing)`. You have to put the method around all of the numbers - otherwise, python is simply asking itself "is a tuple containing the number four equal to True or False" which is complete nonsense (and in fact returns True).
Completed code:

```
list4 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
if message.content.startswith('FindNumber2') or message.content.startswith("1") or\
message.content.startswith("3") or message.content.startswith("4"):
    time.sleep(2)
    await message.channel.send(str(random.choices(list4, weights=(100, 30, 59, 40)))[2])
```